# System language changue to spanish

Tags: system, language

I have a problem with the panel elementary OS Freya, I update the system and then I change the language to spanish using the "configuration system",when i close the session all system changed,but not the panel.

Answer (score 1):

What is the process you follow to install the spanish language? It should be as follows (at least is how I installed spanish several times):

- Go to System settings > Language and region
- Unlock the field edition with your password.
- Click the "+" symbol and select your spanish variant. Wait until it finishes the installation. When it is ready, you may say the following message "Language compatibility is not completely installed" (or something similar). In this case, click on "complete installation".
- Select spanish on the language list on the left.
- Select your region and your format on the drop-down lists.
- Click on "Change system language" and in "Change language".
- Reboot or close and open session again.

Comment: i always follow this steps and nothing has happened